# From Qt3 to Qt4 : issues with internal classes ( Q3GList & Q3PtrCollection )

Tags: c++, qt4, porting, qt3

I'm updating a code from Qt3 to Qt4. I used qt3to4 porting tool, and it fixed some of my issues. But a few errors are remaining:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o CONVECTION_DYN_CODE_version_initiale Convection_points.o Convection_points_prof.o glbox.o globjwin.o main.o algebra.o evector.o matrix.o matrix4.o quaternion.o write_binary.o write_binary_normals.o moc_glbox.o moc_globjwin.o   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtOpenGL -lQtGui -lQtCore -lGLU -lglut -lGL -lpthread -lCGAL -fp-model -lboost_thread -lgmp
glbox.o:(.rodata._ZTI7Q3GList[typeinfo for Q3GList]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Q3PtrCollection'
```

&

```
glbox.o:(.rodata._ZTV7Q3GList[vtable for Q3GList]+0x18): undefined reference to `Q3GList::clear()'
glbox.o:(.rodata._ZTV7Q3GList[vtable for Q3GList]+0x20): undefined reference to `Q3GList::~Q3GList()'
glbox.o:(.rodata._ZTV7Q3GList[vtable for Q3GList]+0x28): undefined reference to `Q3GList::~Q3GList()'
glbox.o:(.rodata._ZTV7Q3GList[vtable for Q3GList]+0x30): undefined reference to `Q3PtrCollection::newItem(void*)'
...
```

Both `Q3GList` and `Q3PtrCollection` are internal classes. I added the corresponding headers but I still got these errors. I don't know how to fix it since it seems to be internal issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should reimplement code parts that depend on Qt3. Qt3Support module will be abandoned. What kept your app to use Qt3 for 7 years after Qt 4 release?

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid re-implementing these parts of the code. But it doesn't seem to be an option. I'm updating some code to add some tools to it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also link against `qt3support` module.

Add

```
QT += qt3support
```

to your project settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to "link against" qt3support module but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @Kamouth, did `-lqt3support` add to your link command? (that is first line in your post)

Comment: I added QT += qt3support (not -lqt3support) and modified a bit my .pro and it works (I haven't understood well what was wrong with my .pro). Thank you for helping some random newbie like me :)